# OpenGL - Samplers in opengl 3.1?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I'm using samplers quite frequently in my application and everything has been working fine.

The problem is, I can only use opengl 3.1 on my laptop. According to the documentation, samplers are only available at opengl 3.3 or higher, but here's where I'm getting a bit confused.

I can use 'glGenSamplers' just fine, no errors are generated and the sampler ID seems fine as well. When using 'glBindSampler' on a valid texture, I get a 'GL_INVALID_VALUE​' error.

Can anyone clear this up for me? If samplers aren't available in opengl 3.1, why can I use glGenSamplers without a problem?

What can I do to provide backwards compatibility? I'm guessing my only option will be to set the texture parameters every time the texture is being used for rendering, if samplers aren't available?

Comment: Samplers are bound to a texture unit, not a texture name / object.

Comment: For backwards compatibility, just set the sampler state per-texture object like the API was originally designed. Don't set it each time you use the texture, unless you have to change it (e.g. need a different filter mode from the last time you used *that* texture).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. Your graphics card/driver supports `ARB_sampler_objects`, in this case it is unsurprising that the function is supported. Feel free to use it.
2. The function is present anyway. In this case, strange as it sounds, you are **not** allowed to use it.

Check whether `glGetStringi(GL_EXTENSION, ...)` returns the sampler objects extension at some index. Only functionality from extensions that the implementation advertizes as "supported" is allowed to be used.
If you find some functions despite no support, they *might* work anyway, but they might as well not. It's undefined.

Note that although you would normally expect the function being named `glGenSamplersARB` when it comes from an ARB extension, that is not the case here, since this is a "backwards extension" that provides selected functionality which is present *identically* in a later version on hardware which isn't able to provide the full functionality of that later version.

(About the error code, note comment by Brett Hale)

Comment: Thank you. I've installed the OpenGL Extensions Viewer, which shows that certain functionalities from opengl 3.2 and 3.3 are supported, including samplers.